# react-bootstrap-table missing styles

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am new bee trying out react, react-bootstrap-table, I followed the example code, but unable to render table with style.
in my table class I am importing the bootstrap css

```
import 'react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
```

inspect element shows head tag renders css, but still my table is not formatted, [image: table image],
 Created this project in github  [github project](https://github.com/fachhoch/react-gs.git), please advice what is missing.
To run the porject  git clone, npm install npm start.

Comment: adding bootstrap, jquery js  and bootstrap css to header resolved the issues, is this  way in react?  to  include js and css files in header?

Comment: Did you add the following:

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Please see here: https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/blob/master/examples/index.html#L6

Comment: A better approach is using webpack, but you will have to do more configurations. If you're starting maybe is better just to set the scripts manually as you did.

Answer (score 3):

In index.html file. 
Add this line for your stylesheet. Works.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```